# child form validation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

hello I'm using a child form validation in a parent form. I'm using a dialog box form validations using jsp and jquery, and call the validations like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
    jQuery("#clientsForm").validationEngine();
    $("#addClientForm").validationEngine();
});
```

on the save option of the dialog box like

```
$( "#edit-client-dialog-form" ).dialog({
            //autoOpen: false,
            height: 425,
            width: 475,
            //modal: true,
            //resizable: true,

            buttons: {
                "Save": function() {

                    //if(!$('#addClientForm').validate())
                    if(!$('#addClientForm').validationEngine());

                        {
                        alert('validation success');
                        }
                            $.post( '<c:url value="'+action+'" />'
                                    , $('#addClientForm').serialize()
                                    , alert("Edited SuccessFuly.."),

                                      $( this ).dialog( "close" )                                                   
                                         );

                            searchByCriteria('radio');                  
                },
```

but validations are not working on the save button, it will save the text fields without validating.

Comment: Why jQuery().validationEngine() AND $().validationEngin() at the same time? Also what is a child form?

Comment: @mplungjan - jQuery().validationEngine() AND $().validationEngin()  both have the same meaning, a child form is a form which we will define within another form, means one is main form or parent form and another one will be child form in the same jsp page.

Comment: Does not make me any more informed. Where I come from, a form cannot be nested